# GNUPG / GPG / S3 / Duplicity gpg: no default secret key: secret key not available

Tags: gnupg, duplicity

I am using an S3 / duplicity [back up script](http://kappataumu.com/articles/cloud-backups-duplicity-s3.html), save my files. It has been working just fine, until I added a second gpg key. Then all hell broke loose. I tried to deal with two keys, then I deleted the second key. Then I remove / purged gpg altogether and started with a fresh start.

I created a new key and this is the response I get.

```
GPGError: GPG Failed, see log below:
===== Begin GnuPG log =====
gpg: no default secret key: secret key not available
gpg: [stdin]: sign+encrypt failed: secret key not available
===== End GnuPG log =====
```

`
Here is my back up script (but I don't think that is the problem)

```
#!/bin/bash

# Make GPG explicitly aware of our private key,
# since we'll be running this via cron as root


HOME="/" SOURCE="/" TARGET=s3+http://xxxx/xxxxx/
LOGFILE=/home/bege/.duplicity/desktop.log export HOME=$HOME export
SOURCE=$SOURCE export TARGET=$TARGET export LOGFILE=$LOGFILE

# Load our credentials source "/home/bege/Desktop/.credentials.conf"

export PASSPHRASE export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID export
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

GPG_KEY='7E4B6B9B'

duplicity \
    --verbosity notice \
    --s3-use-new-style \
    --volsize=1000 \
    --encrypt-key="$GPG_KEY" \
    --sign-key="$GPG_KEY" \
    --full-if-older-than 7D \
    --asynchronous-upload \
    --log-file "/home/bege/.duplicity/log.log" \
    --include=/home/bege/Desktop/charts \
    --exclude=/** \
    --progress \
    $SOURCE \
    $TARGET > $LOGFILE

unset PASSPHRASE unset AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID unset AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
```

Here are the details of my keys:

```
/home/bege/.gnupg/pubring.gpg
-----------------------------
pub   2048R/7E4B6B9B 2015-07-15
uid                  Chad H <me@mail.com>

/home/bege/.gnupg/secring.gpg
-----------------------------
sec   2048R/7E4B6B9B 2015-07-15
uid                  Chad H <me@mail.com>
```

I have also modified the `conf` file to make this key the default one. I have spent far too much time on this but I'm obssessed for some lame reason, I'm at my wits end, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the help of NIIBE, the problem was:

> I re-read your original post again, and found that you redefine the
>   environment variable "HOME" in the script, which is the cause of the
>   trouble.
>
> Please add two lines in your script:
>
> ```
> GNUPGHOME=/home/bege/.gnupg
> export GNUPGHOME
> ```
>
> Then, please try with new script.  After you set `GNUPGHOME`, gpg command will access that directory.
>
> (Please note that secret subkey for encryption is also needed.)

Hopefully this will save somebody some time someday.